# TAing for two young hotshot postdocs (possible "in" for future research)? or TAing a lab with more student engagement?

Tags: career-path, early-career, teaching-assistant

Incoming theoretical physics PhD student in the US.

I hope to get into academia after my PhD.

When listing TA preferences, would it behoove my career goal more to list as my top preference a course that is being taught by to young "up and coming" hotshot postdocs in my fields? Or (as a theorist whose job prospects may increase by having some lab experience) would TAing a lab which enables more engagement with students be a better choice?

The course TA could potentially just be a grading job, which doesn't help my career objectives, whereas the lab experience and more experience with students would.

Thoughts?

Comment: Normally a TA job is assisting in teaching - grading and leading smaller review sections of a large course. It doesn't involve research at all. An RA, on the other hand, assists in research. TA job is good for future academics as it gives a bit of a hint of teaching that nearly everyone does as part of the career, but it isn't research related.

Comment: Oh I know, sorry let me elaborate. Just the contact "in" that comes with communicating about the course with those postdocs could lead to research.

Comment: And unfortunately, at this university, TA jobs are entirely grading or lab (unless you work something out personally with a professor who is open to your leading small recitations).

Comment: Maybe. Tentative. Doubtful. There are probably more direct and productive ways to get an "in". I suspect that a TA job is there to free the post doc from the scut work they don't want to do so they can focus on their own stuff. A professor's job is to assist you, but a post doc is mostly there for their own career needs.

Comment: You are likely right! Thank you for the perspective! :)

Comment: I'd argue that the choice should be TAing the class with the topic that is most closely aligned with your interests.

Comment: What @mlk said. Also, if you want to build rapport with one of the lecturers, e.g. for getting a reference letter from them, it's probably best to go with them, just so they know you better. (But then do it really well!)

Comment: None of the information you have provided will help you decide what to TA.

Comment: As far as things worth considering with regard to TA assignments, these are like o(epsilon^4).